# how write mysql query for the following stock inventory tables?

Tags: mysql

products table **table1** which has item names

| item_cid | item_id | item_name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 8 | 403 | Tequila1 |
| 8 | 404 | Tequila2 |
| 8 | 405 | Tequila3 |
| 8 | 406 | Tequila4 |
| 8 | 407 | Tequila5 |
| 8 | 408 | Tequila6 |
| 2 | 409 | budwiser1 |
| 2 | 5 | budwiser2 |
| 2 | 7 | budwiser4 |
| 2 | 8 | budwiser5 |

**table2** which has a current stock

| item_cid | item_id | item_name | current stock |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 8 | 403 | Tequila1 | 11 |
| 8 | 404 | Tequila2 | 10 |
| 8 | 405 | Tequila3 | 32 |
| 8 | 406 | Tequila4 | 44 |
| 2 | 409 | budwiser1 | 55 |
| 2 | 5 | budwiser2 | 58 |

**table3** which has purchase stock

| item_cid | item_id | item_name | purchase qty |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 8 | 407 | Tequila5 | 4 |
| 8 | 408 | Tequila6 | 7 |
| 2 | 7 | budwiser4 | 8 |
| 2 | 8 | budwiser5 | 9 |
| 2 | 409 | budwiser1 | 5 |
| 2 | 5 | budwiser2 | 2 |

the result I want

| item_cid | item_id | item_name | current stock | purchase qty | total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 8 | 403 | Tequila1 | 11 | null | 11 |
| 8 | 404 | Tequila2 | 10 | null | 10 |
| 8 | 405 | Tequila3 | 32 | null | 32 |
| 8 | 406 | Tequila4 | 44 | null | 44 |
| 8 | 407 | Tequila5 | null | 4 | 4 |
| 8 | 408 | Tequila6 | null | 7 | 7 |
| 2 | 409 | budwiser1 | 55 | 5 | 60 |
| 2 | 5 | budwiser2 | 58 | 2 | 60 |
| 2 | 7 | budwiser4 | null | 8 | 8 |
| 2 | 8 | budwiser5 | null | 9 | 9 |

the query I tried is not able to retrieve rows from  table 3 in the final result  this what I am getting

| item_cid | item_id | item_name | current stock | purchase qty | total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 8 | 403 | Tequila1 | 11 | null | 11 |
| 8 | 404 | Tequila2 | 10 | null | 10 |
| 8 | 405 | Tequila3 | 32 | null | 32 |
| 8 | 406 | Tequila4 | 44 | null | 44 |
| 8 | 407 | Tequila5 | null | 4 | 4 |
| 8 | 408 | Tequila6 | null | 7 | 7 |
| 2 | 409 | budwiser1 | 55 | 5 | 60 |
| 2 | 5 | budwiser2 | 58 | 2 | 60 |

```
SELECT 
   *

FROM
   table2 a
       LEFT JOIN
   table3 b ON a.item_id = b.item_id
        JOIN
   table1 d ON  d.item_id=a.item_id
   ORDER BY a.item_id
```

Comment: @NicoHaase query I tried was not able to retrieve some of rows from table3 purchase stock into final result

Comment: Yep that's what you said in the question - please publish the query and we'll see if we can point out where you went wrong. Also publish table definitions as text and preferably sample data as insert statements

Comment: @NicoHaase can you check my question i have updated it

Comment: @P.Salmon can you check my question i have updated it  with details u asked

Comment: Please share more details, like the table structure and your attempts to resolve the problem. This makes it easier to reproduce your problem, and provide help afterwards

Comment: The order of the joins does matter and since table1 contains all items which can be in stock and/or purchased you should be driving FROM table1 and left joining the other 2 tables. NB if there can be many purchases consider a sub query summing by product.

Comment: @NicoHaase i have mentioned desired output and also the output I am getting I am not getting output I am I want that's the problem

Comment: @P.Salmon  thanks for reply can u write an example query if possible

Answer (score 0):

You need to SELECT from the product table first for including All products and then join other tables to get extra informations from them.

Try this :

```
SELECT a.item_cid, a.item_id, a.item_name, b.current_stock, c.purchase_qty, b.current_stock + c.purchase_qty AS 'Total'
FROM table1 AS a
LEFT JOIN table2 AS b ON a.item_id=b.item_id
LEFT JOIN table3 AS c ON a.item_id=c.item_id
ORDER BY a.item_id
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it